# Any ideas on how to get PHP form to return to particular row/column?

Tags: php, forms, scroll, position, return

Hoping for some brainstorming here. I have a PHP app that submits a form and returns to a page with lots of columns and rows (scrolls in both x and y). Any ideas of how I might be able to get the screen to return to center on a particular ?

I'm open to just about any solution!

Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CSS style ID's.

If you add `#someTag` at the end of your URL, the page will try to scroll to the matching ID.  So, put unique ID's on your table Rows, and add the ID if the row to scroll to either to the redirect after the form, or the form action.

Comment: Perfect! I did <td id=\"Owner_Info_{$row['Project_ID']}\"></td> then made the form processor do a redirect at the end
header("Location: http://www.website.com#Owner_Info_$projectID"); /* Redirect browser */

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an identifier to the cell you want to focus on and use the following javascript:

`document.getElementById("myAnchor").focus();`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp